# get post id from wp_insert_post for get_template_part

Tags: php, posts, functions, wp-insert-post

This is my code:

```
$my_post = array(
    'post_type'  => 'theposttt',
    'post_title'    => 'test',
    'post_content'  => '',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_author'   => 1
);

$data = wp_insert_post($my_post);

ob_start();
get_template_part( 'template/the', 'post' );
$data = ob_get_clean();

$resp = array(
    'success'   => true,
    'msg'       => 'success',
    'data'      => $data
);
```

I want to get the post id of the new post from wp_insert_post to using it inside the template the-post.php that I get it by using the get_template_part function.

Comment: Would you please describe what you actually wanna accomplish ? Cause this way you can't create and show post in one file like this. At least not in any WP way. So please describe what you want actually and may be we can suggest a better way to do it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `$my_post_id` as global in your code. Declare `$my_post_id` as global in `the-post.php` template. Your code:

```
global $my_post_id;
$my_post = array(
    'post_type'  => 'theposttt',
    'post_title'    => 'test',
    'post_content'  => '',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_author'   => 1
);
$my_post_id = wp_insert_post($my_post);
if(is_wp_error($my_post_id))
    $my_post_id = 0;
```

Now, you can use `$my_post_id` in `the-post.php` template. Possible values: 0 ( failure ), post id ( success ).